# Ionic 3 - Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

i'm trying to delete an individual object from array, how do i do it? 
i tried to use `this.storage.remove('details')` as ionic instructed [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) but it will delete all the array, here is my current attempt:

it gives me an error "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target"

```
  private details: {name: string, fav: string}[] = []; 

  hapusDetail(val) {
  let test: string[] = [val]

  this.storage.remove(toString(test)) //really lost here
  //console.log(val)
  }


> Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
> Ionic Framework Version: 3.1.1
> Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
> Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
> Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.6
> ios-deploy version: Not installed
> ios-sim version: Not installed
> OS: Linux 4.8
> Node Version: v6.10.2
> Xcode version: Not installed
```

`val` contains desired object to be deleted e.g. {name: john, fav: apple}

basically what i need is to delete {name: john, fav: apple} from an array which contains {name: bob, fav: banana}, {name: ed, fav: grape}, {name: john, fav: apple}

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is because you're firing a command with the wrong properties/types. My guess is it's the remove command. I don't know if you have a function called `toString()` but my guess is that's the problem. Try making it a basic string like `'UserData'` and see if the error still shows.

That won't fix your actual issue though,

Storage is specifically related to the saved set of data on the user's device. If you want to remove a specific item from the array (Just for the moment) you need to first figure out what it's position is, and then remove it from the array.

Example:

```js
let myArray = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'];

// find oranges
let position = myArray.indexOf('oranges');

//splice it out
myArray.splice(position, 1);
```

If you want to remove it from the locally stored data too you just need to do your action on the whole array FIRST then STORE it not remove it. When you store objects with Ionic you give them names, your code actually looks like you intend to convert the value to a string.

Let me break it down a bit:

```js
// Get the saved stuff, Ionic will convert it for you
let userData = this.storage.get('UserData');

// Lets say favorite fruit is a value of the user data.

let fruit = userData.fruit; // ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas']

// find oranges
let position = myArray.indexOf('oranges');

//splice it out, remember fruit is a shorthand reference to userData.fruit
fruit.splice(position, 1);

// Now, the data we save/load is called 'UserData' it has nothing to do with the data itself

this.storage.set('UserData', userData);
```

Hope that helps..